# Python - Combining n different json files/dictionaries (n could vary)

Tags: python, json, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I tried search for this particular question with the keywords in the question but could not figure out a good solution.

Say I have a list of JSON files(lets assume the top level is always going to be a dictionary):

```
"../data/Flickr_EXIF_0.json",
"../data/Flickr_EXIF_150.json",
"../data/Flickr_EXIF_300.json",
"../data/Flickr_EXIF_450.json",
```

The question is to combine/merge all the json files into one single file.

It would be of course simple to do that given we know how many JSON files we are merging like,

```
with open("../data/Flickr_EXIF_0.json", "r") as jFl:
    obj1 = json.load(jFl)

with open("../data/Flickr_EXIF_150.json", "r") as jFl:
    obj2 = json.load(jFl) 

with open("../data/Flickr_EXIF_300.json", "r") as jFl:
    obj3 = json.load(jFl) 

with open("../data/Flickr_EXIF_450.json", "r") as jFl:
    obj4 = json.load(jFl) 

d = {**obj1, **obj2, **obj3, **obj4}
```

But **how would you say write a function that can combine an unknown number of JSONs**. I am looking for a pythonic solution.

This is my partial solution, which throws an error:

```
def appendJSON(*inpFl):
    flObjs = []
    for fl in inpFl:
        with open(fl, "r") as jFl:
            flObjs.append(json.load(jFl))

    # something smart here! 
    itemsList = [list(objs.items()) for objs in flObjs]

    return dict(itemsList)
```

Error:

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        20 "../data/Flickr_EXIF_1350.json",
>        21 "../data/Flickr_EXIF_1500.json",
>   ---> 22 "../data/Flickr_EXIF_1650.json")
>
> in appendJSON(*inpFl)
>         7         itemsList = [objs.items() for objs in flObjs]
>         8 
>   ----> 9         return dict(itemsList)
>        10 
>        11 objs = appendJSON("../data/Flickr_EXIF_0.json",
>
> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 150; 2 is
>   required

Sample Debug values for `itemsList`:

```
[[('5822864395',
   {'date': '2010-06-10 14:48:25',
    'height': 2592,
    'lat': 0.0,
    'long': 0.0,
    'orientation': 0,
    'width': 2818}),
   ('1458886548',
   {'date': '2007-09-22 02:59:20',
    'height': 768,
    'lat': 39.145372,
    'long': -84.508981,
    'orientation': 0,
    'width': 1024})]]
```

Alternate solution,

```
def appendJSON(*inpFl):
    flObjs = []
    for fl in inpFl:
        with open(fl, "r") as jFl:
            flObjs.append(json.load(jFl))

    for i in range(1,len(flObjs)):
        flObjs[0].update(flObjs[i])

    return flObjs[0]
```

Comment: are you going to share the error with us?

Comment: Oh sure. Sorry about that! @DanFarrell

Comment: Thanks.  Why are you trying to turn a list of dicts into a dict?  How do you expect that to work, exactly?

Comment: If it was two simple dictionaries, then having an appended list of dict items can be easily converted into a dictionary back again. 
Ex: 
`d1 = {'hello' : 'world'}
d2 = {'stack' : 'overflow'}

dict(list(d1.items()) + list(d2.items()))
{'hello': 'world', 'stack': 'overflow'}
`

Comment: I wish I could format it right! @DanFarrell

Comment: I think you have to flatten your lists. have you debugged the value of `itemsList`?  It should be a list of lists of tuples.  You want a flat list of tuples to turn back into a dict.

Comment: I've added a sample value for `itemsList` @DanFarrell

Comment: looks like I'm onto something here.  See howthat list has a list in it?

Comment: I am type casting here, `list(objs.items())` inside a list comprehension, I guess that should explain. Also, I have to say I do have a solution to this but I am looking for something smart! My solution works but I am not impressed with what I have! :)

Comment: Please update your post with the following information: Are your JSON files restricted to having dicts at the top-level?  You seem to be assuming that but of course the top level can be a list as well and then simple "updating" by the next JSON file is impossible, and a different (or more general strategy needs to be followed).

Comment: @Anthon: True. I updated the question title, for the sake of this question lets say they are just a bunch of dictionaries. But for the general method I am making I will make sure to consider the case where the top level is a `list`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first make a generic solution, then optionally optimize if the types of the top-levels of the JSON file are all the same (i.e. all object/dict, or all array/list).

If you have a mix of top-level types after loading (dict, list, value), you are not going to be able to combine them anyway. You can only combine them if every loaded data is a dict or every loaded is a list. If you have a combination or if you have one or more values at the toplevel, you cannot combine.

The generic approach is to have  create an empty list and `.append()` the data loaded by `json.load()` to it, while keeping track of having, dict, list or values:

```
def combine(json_file_names):
    combined = []
    have_dict = False
    have_list = False
    for file_name in json_file_names:
        data = json.load(file_name)
        combined.append(data)
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            have_dict = True
        elif isinstance(data, list):
            have_list = True
        else:
            have_list = have_dict = True

    # if have_list and have_dict have the same value, either there is nothing 
    # loaded or it's a mixed bag. In both cases you can't do anything
    if have_list == have_dict:  
        return combined
    if have_list:
        tmp = []
        for elem in combined:
            tmp.extend(elem)
    else:  # have_dict
        tmp = {}
        for elem in combined:
            tmp.update(elem)
    return tmp
```

Please note that when combing all-top-level-dicts you overwrite key-value pairs from previous loaded data.

Answer (score 0):

Since json is easily convertible to Python dict, all you need to do is read all the json files into dictionaries, merge all dictionaries, convert to json and save it to a file.

Comment: This could have been a comment.

Comment: If you save a list as a JSON file ( `json.dump([1, 2, 3])`) how are you going to "easily convert" that to a dict? Do you just assign the list to a random key value?